# Return ISO Week list where it crosses over another year using python

Tags: python, pandas, strptime

I am trying to convert a yyyyww which is actually starting as a string object I think at is like 201731. I want to capture the last 6 weeks including its self.

```
def generate_6_last_week(yearweek):
    weeks = [int(yearweek)]
    date = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(str(yearweek)+"0","%Y%W%w").timetuple())
    for i in range(1,6):
        date = date-604800 # 60*60*24*7
        weeks.append(int(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(date)).strftime('%Y%W')))
    return weeks

generate_6_last_week(201731)
```

so the output for 201731 should be:

```
 [201731, 201730, 201729, 201728, 201727, 201726]
```

and this seems to work, the problem is if i test it with a crossover year like 201702 it returns this:

```
   [201702, 201701, 201700, 201651, 201650, 201649]
```

Which also looks pretty good, but I need it in ISO weeks so there shouldnt be a week 00 I think and the last week of a year should be either 53 or 52 but not the 51.

Any ideas how to adapt this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires the "isoweek" package to be installed but gave me what i want with some manipulation of the format of my str YYYYWW and works well with the crossover years.

```
from isoweek import Week
yearweek = "201702"

weeks = [int(yearweek)]

x = 1
for i in range(5):
    week = int(str(Week(int(yearweek[:4]), int(yearweek[-2:])-x)).replace("W",""))
    weeks.append(week)
    x +=1

print(weeks)
```

## or in a function format.

```
def generate_6_last_week(yearweek):
    weeks = [int(yearweek)]
    x = 1
    for i in range(5):
        week = int(str(Week(int(yearweek[:4]), int(yearweek[-2:])-x)).replace("W",""))

        weeks.append(week)
        x +=1

    print(weeks)

generate_6_last_week("201702")
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about `striptime()`. So I have solved the problem by writing my own code. Here's the code:

```
date=input()

a=int(date[0:4])
b=int(date[4:])

k=5-b

finallist=[]

def m(x,y):
    return(x-y)


if b>=5:
    date=int(date)
    finallist=[date,date-1,date-2,date-3,date-4,date-5]
    print(finallist)

else:
    date=int(date)
    for i in range(b+1):
        finallist.append(date)
        date-=1
    a-=1
    b=52
    date=int(str(a)+str(b))
    for i in range(k):
        finallist.append(date)
        date-=1
    print(finallist)
```

> `201700` gives `[201700, 201652, 201651, 201650, 201649, 201648]`
>
> `201702` gives `[201702, 201701, 201700, 201652, 201651, 201650]`

**ALITER**: There's a much easier way to do this. Just add 1 to those specific list items in your list :p

Comment: thanks for the workaround M.Hamel but need a more clearer robust way. I think I found another hack but requires the isoweek package.